# path /tmp does not correspond to a regular file

Tags: linux, redhat, selinux

this happens when I have

- an executable that is in the /tmp directory (say /tmp/a.out)
- it is run by a root shell
- linux
- selinux on (default for RedHat, CentOS, etc)

Apparently trying to run an executable that sits in the /tmp/directory as root revokes the privileges. Any idea how to go around this issue, other than turning off selinux? Thanks

Comment: whats the error its showing, and what is command you trying to run?

Comment: Did my answer worked for you?

Comment: Ricardo, please respond. And select appropriate answer.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, I finally figured out what was wrong. khrm had the right answer, the semanage worked. Luis Colorado suggestion made sense, and I have systems that are more secure because I mount /tmp in memory and with the no-exec option, but that was not the case here. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set file context on binary or directory (containing binary) that are in /tmp that you want to run.

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t bin_t /tmp/location
```

Then restorecon:

```
sudo restorecon -vR /tmp/location
```

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at the mount options for `/tmp` directory, most probably you have `no-exec` option on it (there are many security reasons of doing that, the first being that anyone can put a file in the `/tmp` directory)

Comment: While this is true. But OP is facing some other issue. SELinux  blocks execution in /tmp folder. For this my answer is more accurate.

Comment: Probably SELinux is blocking execution in `/tmp` folder by using that option on mounting `/tmp`

Comment: It uses fcontext . That's why I posted to change fcontext to bin_t

Comment: Yes, having the no-exec option on places like /tmp would make sense. But that was not the case here. Using the semanage worked. Thanks!

Comment: SELinux is a good option to avoid executing software that anybody can put in the `/tmp` directory.  I continue trying to understand the nature of the problem... What's the sense to use SELinux if you are then going to allow execution of binaries in an all writable directory?  Also, this is not a competition to see which response is more accurate.  We are all volunteers trying to solve other's problems.  The intention is to help somebody, not to win a race.  Let me upvote you, so you'll be before me in the race.